# 'npm install' executed via another npm script affects package.json 'dependencies' list

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Say, we have `package.json` with a script that should install some package locally that we had built and packed before:

```
{
  "name": "test-local-npm-install",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "pack-package": "npm pack ./dist",
    "install-package": "npm install my-package-0.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

When I execute `npm run install-package`, the package is being installed properly, I can see it in my `./node_modules/my-package`. But npm also affects my `package.json`, it adds that package to the `dependencies` list:

```
{
  "name": "test-local-npm-install",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "pack-package": "npm pack ./dist",
    "install-package": "npm install my-package-0.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "my-package": "file:my-package-0.0.0.tgz"
  }
}
```

I'm wondering why? There are no `--save` / `--save-dev` flags... How to prevent this behaviour? I need it to be installed in `node_modules` but I don't want it to be added to `package.json`.

Comment: Because your application depends on it?

Comment: @marekful I realized that currently `npm install <package>` saves package by default. It was not true for npm < 5... My app produces that package and there is some additional testing procedure that requires it to be installed to `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1):

The time passes quickly... Since npm 5 had been released (2017), the default behaviour is changed. Per [current documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> **npm install** saves any specified packages into **dependencies** by default.

To solve the issue it needs to be called with `--no-save` option:

> Additionally, you can control where and how they get saved with some
>   additional flags:
>   ... 
>   **--no-save**: Prevents saving to dependencies.